# XPath.Clear Method Not working for IOS Simulator

Tags: java, xcode, selenium, ios-simulator, appium-ios

After Updating Xcode to 11.3.1, Xpath.clear method is not working in Simulator 12.1. Using Java platform

Comment: Post your code and explain *not working*.

Comment: mobWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(xpath));
   xpath.clear();
   xpath.sendKeys(msg);
Before Xcode Updated it was Working for validation of user name and password. Now previous data not clear while enter next Data